# What's the term to describe an algorithm that has the same complexity as the underlying prroblem?

Tags: terminology, complexity-theory

Whilst researching data structures for a project a few months back, I came across a term that I quite liked, that could be used as follows:

> This [Algorithm/Solution/Data structure] is ?????ally-optimal

Meaning that the time (or space, depending on context) complexity of the solution being referred to is the same as the fundamental complexity as the problem it solves.

For example, if we ignore quantum computation and accept that problem of sorting is `O(n log n)` time in the general case, then with respect to time complexity heap sort is ?????ally-optimal because its complexity is also `O(n log n)`, whereas bubble sort is not ?????ally-optimal because `O(n^2)` is worse than `O(n log n)`.

I have no idea where I read it, I've so far failed to find it with google, and not being able to remember it has been bothering me ever since!

Comment: I don't think that "the problem of sorting is O(n log n)" is a meaningful statement. *Problems* fall into different hardness classes, and *algorithms* have asymptotic complexities. At best you can say that "any sorting algorithm has asymptotic complexity at least O(n log n)" and try and prove that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Agreed, it was a colloquialism I probably shouldn't have used given that the question was about terminology! What I meant by it was "there exists a proof that no algorithm with an asymptotic complexity better than O(n log n) can solve the problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are talking about [Asymptotically optimal algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Asymptotically_optimal_algorithm):

> In computer science, an algorithm is said to be asymptotically optimal if, roughly speaking, for large inputs it performs at worst a constant factor (independent of the input size) worse than the best possible algorithm.

Comment: I think that must've been it , it certainly conveys the meaning I wanted the term to - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Are you thinking computationally optimal?</strike> probably "asymptotically optimal," like another answer said.  It seems what you're describing is big-theta:

If a problem has been proven to take at least f(x), it is called Omega(f(x)); an algorithm's worst case is big-O(g(x)).  When f(x) == g(x), that is to say the worst case for the solution is the best case for the problem, the algorithm is big-theta(f(x)).  So heapsort, e.g. is theta(n*log(n)).

Comment: Cheers - I wasn't aware of the big-theta notation before